# How to append particular list in other python file and save it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to change the items in the list saved in other python file

file A.py

```
items = ['A','B','C']
```

file B.py

```
import A

A.items.append('D')
```

it works, but when I restart the script it switch to the previous version.

Comment: When you start A.py, it will only contain A,B,C. Even if you append 'D' in A.py, on restart it will only contain A,B,C. You have to save the data to a file, and load it back when starting.

Comment: What's your goal? Seems like you might want to move the data out of `A` and put it in another file like a CSV or JSON so it's easier to modify

Comment: Maybe use a light-weight database instead?

Comment: @Sri How to load and save files?

Comment: You can just use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for converting string to a list if your list is basic.

Comment: @wjandrea I can use JSON but I have other functionalities too can I modify any *.py file?

Comment: @MayankJain modifing a code file is not a solution.

Comment: @Mayank If `items` contains Python objects, I think you can use the `pickle` module. Don't edit the code.

Comment: @wjandrea can you explain it with example for my use-case as I'm new to python. Thanks btw

Comment: @Mayank First please [edit] the question to give more details about your use case. Welcome btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the data in a file to save it.

In this script I have the items list in file A, file B adds 'D' to the list, and then adds 
it to a txt file.

You can print the txt file in file A after you run file B to see the new items list. The new list gets saved as new_items

If you run file B multiple times, it will add the list more then once.

File A:

```
items = ['A','B','C']

#prints out the txt file
with open("items.txt","r") as f:
    new_items = f.read()
    new_items = new_items.split()
    print(new_items)
    f.close()
```

File B:

```
import A

#Adds 'D' to the items list and stores it as a new variable
A.items.append('D')
items = A.items

#Writes the data to a txt file
with open('items.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(str(items))
```

Comment: What if we want also use the list, not just print out?

Comment: I just fixed the code a bit, you can use new_items as your new items list.

Comment: No, you can't. It is a ``str`` instance. It is not a list.

Comment: Try it now, It should be store as a list

Comment: Are you writing these comments without trying to run your code and see the output? It is a list but it is not about what we are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

When an application exits, the memory used by that application is freed. This is why we need files, we can write our data into files. Also actions that your code does while running don't affects any source code.

If your `items` will be a list of strings you can use a lightweight solution like this:

```py
#a.py
import os, ast

items = ['A','B','C']

file = "data.txt" # the file we will write our data in

if os.path.exists(file): # if our file exists
    with open(file, "r") as f: # open it in 'r'ead mode
        items = ast.literal_eval(f.read()) # read it and evalute
else: # if our file doesn't exists
    with open(file, "w") as f: # open it in 'w'rite mode
        f.write(str(items)) # write str(items) into file
```

```py
#b.py
import a

a.items.append("D")

with open("data.txt", "w") as f: # open our file in 'w'rite mode
    f.write(str(a.items)) # save a.items
```

As a general solution, you can also use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module for saving lists or other objects.

---

Docs:

[ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), 
[os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html)

Comment: Is there an advantage to saving Python literals over JSON or Pickle?

Comment: Pickle can save almost any python object, JSON can save only basic types. ``ast.literal_eval`` is not a general solution, it is a basic example for OP's situation.